# Where do I find my asked questions on LeetCode?

Tags: website

I have posted questions in the discussion sections of several different questions on [leetcode.com](https://leetcode.com/), but I forgot some of the question numbers. Where do I find a collection of my asked questions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found it in "Recent Posts" under my profile page. First click top right-most your profile picture, then your user name, then you can find the posts!

[image]